# How to unpack list of tuples and rewrite table in multiple rows in a column SQLITE3 Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, mysql-python

I am trying to update my table with new values in a list. I am new to SQLITE3 with Python3 so please speak english lol.

The table currently looks like this:

`\/\/` `column1`
`row1` `abc`
`row2` `def`

The table should save like this:

`\/\/` `column1`
`row1` `abc`
`row2` `def`
`row3` `ghi`

The list I want to unpack looks like this:

`[("abc",), ("def",), ("ghi",)]`

I want it so that it does NOT insert the new values but work as if it clears the current table then inserts the new values into the table.

I have tried this:

`db_cursor.executemany("REPLACE INTO allowed_tables VALUES (?);", self.allowed_tables)` which seems to actually just insert the values into the table which leaves me with twice as many values if I try to resave the table with the same list 2 times.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Why not just delete all current rows before insertion?

Comment: truncate the table (in SQLITE just delete and re-create the table) then insertmany

Comment: Ooo, what is the method/function for truncation in sqlite3?